# How to give log in credential for internet through command line

Tags: linux, command-line, internet, login, backtrack

My GUI for backtrack is not working. I want to connect to internet. I gave the required static IP address to my machine. but the problem is I have to give username and password through the browser before accessing the internet. Now here, I don't have any browser. How can I give the log in credentials through command line in backtrack machine? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of options to try: lynx, links, wget, curl.

Also, why backtrack?